# Is this better than deciding whether to use ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronizationcontext, configureawait

I recently saw this in code:

```
await QueryAsync.ConfigureAwait(SynchronizationContext.Current is not null || TaskScheduler.Current != TaskScheduler.Default)
```

My first thought was, "that's not right", but is it?

My understanding is that if there is no current synchronization context, we should use .ConfigureAwait(false).  If there IS a current synchronization context, we MIGHT (note the UPPER-CASE 'MIGHT') need to use .ConfigureAwait(true), which is basically the same as not using .ConfigureAwait at all.

If my understanding is correct (which it likely is not), that code would work and could be put into an extension for even more brevity.

Am I incorrect?

I have tried testing this and it seems to work in that .ConfigureAwait(true) is called when there is a synchronization context, and .ConfigureAwait(false) when SynchronizationContext.Current is null.

Edit:  To clarify, if there is no current SynchronizationContext AND no custom TaskScheduler, this code evaluates to:

```
await QueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When there IS a current SynchronizationContext, or a custom TaskScheduler, it evaluates to:

```
await QueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

which, according to to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/), is basically the same as:

```
await QueryAsync();
```

Comment: @Dai "When comparing await task with await task.ConfigureAwait(true), they’re functionally identical. If you see ConfigureAwait(true) in production code, you can delete it without ill effect." - from Stephen Toub (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

Comment: @Dai In your first comment, are you saying the "MIGHT need to use ConfigureAwait(true)" isn't necessarily true?  Your comment is very confusing, and appears to have been added in haste without first reading the post - particularly the sentence you referenced.

Comment: I retract my earlier comments - I should have read them properly before posting, sorry guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question:

```
await QueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(SynchronizationContext.Current is not null ||
    TaskScheduler.Current != TaskScheduler.Default);
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
await QueryAsync();
```

The `.ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default, so it can be omitted. In case there is no synchronization context to capture at the `await` point, both `.ConfigureAwait(true)` and `.ConfigureAwait(false)` behave the same.

In other words, this piece of sophisticated code is a whole lot of nothing.

Comment: I agree, it is a basically nothing - WHEN evaluating to true, but what about when it evaluates to false?  For instance, when SynchronizationContext.Current is null and TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default, it amounts to QueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false), which, I believe, is what you would want when there is no sync context or custom task scheduler, right?

Comment: @TadGhostal no. When `SynchronizationContext.Current is null` and `TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default`, the `ConfigureAwait` has no effect. You can give either `true` or `false` as the value of `continueOnCapturedContext`, and the behavior will be exactly the same. The `ConfigureAwait` makes a difference only when an ambient scheduler exists (either a sync-context or a `TaskScheduler`).

Comment: Ah, I see your point.  If we wanted .ConfigureAwait(false), we wouldn't get it except in a case where it would be ignored anyway, and if we wanted .ConfigureAwait(true), well, we wouldn't have to do anything, so, pointless code all around.  I'll mark your answer.  Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @TadGhostal yep, exactly!